# How do I clean up the project files generated by CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake to generate the project files.

Is there a command with which I can clean up all those generated project files?

Comment: If it's a git repository, `git checkout . & git clean -dxf` will wipe everything clean to exactly the state of your git index.

Comment: I also looked for `cmake clean` command yesterday, found none. But now my question is why are there projects still building in root source folder instead of `build`? :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Is there a command with which I can clean up all those generated project files?

Yes - if you do an ***out-of-source build*** (as recommended).

To do so, create a directory - for example, `build` - within your projects directory and run CMake from there:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

(Or tell your IDE to do so.)

Now ***all generated*** files are within `build`. To clean those, just remove the directory (`rm -rf build`).

---

**PRO:** You can keep all generated files out of your versioning system by adding `build` to its ignore ;-)

Comment: Just for completeness: There's no way to do it automatically in-source, is that correct?

Comment: if you call cmake from the root directory of your project it's in-source – all build files are then scattered into your project. Doing an out-of-source build will keep them within one place (eg. `build/`). So it's more an issue of how you use cmake. Did i get your question right?

Comment: This breaks Conan and invites non-portable deletion commands and doesn't integrate well with automation and relies subtle directory changes that cause all sorts of problems.